# WPF - Copying ListView's item cell's text to clipboard using ContextMenu, MVVM and Command

Tags: wpf, listview, mvvm, contextmenu, clipboard

I'm trying to achieve a very simple task: copying a ListView cell's text to clipboard using a right-click context menu, but the task seems to be extremely complex in WPF. I have read several topics and answers, and I've made many attempts, I've also asked ChatGPT, but there is always a problem.

Attempt 1 - putting context menu in cell's template: it cannot find the origin "RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType='System.Windows.Controls.ListView', AncestorLevel=1"

Attempt 2 - Setting ContextMenu through a Style setter for ListView: The command is executed, but parameter is null

Attempt 3 - Using a static command: The command is executed, but parameter is null

Attempt 4 - Setting ListView's ContextMenu attached property: the debug output says it cannot find element "myListView", and it says "CopyToClipboardCommand" property (?) was not found in object of type "TestWindow1ViewModel" (even though everything is wired correctly, as I can "F12" everything correctly in XAML)

Attempt 5 - Setting ListView's ContextMenu attached property and using a static command: The command is executed, but parameter is null

Please tell me what's wrong with these attemps, and how do I tell the ContextMenu to consider the currently selected listView item, or better what is the best way to associate the context menu to the right-clicked element in the listView, and run a command with the associated "Person" as command parameter, thank you.
My **BaseViewModel** and **RelayCommand** classes are correctly working because I've used them successfully in other classes as well.
I have commented all these attemps in XAML, here is the code:

**Person.cs**

```
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

**TestWindow1ViewModel.cs**

```
public class TestWindow1ViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    private ObservableCollection<Person> persons;
    public ObservableCollection<Person> Persons
    {
        get => persons;
        set => SetField(ref persons, value);
    }

    public TestWindow1ViewModel()
    {
        Persons = new ObservableCollection<Person>(new List<Person>
            {
                new Person { Id = 1, Name = "John" }, 
                new Person { Id = 2, Name = "Paul" }
            });
        CopyToClipboardCommand = new RelayCommand(CopyToClipboardCommandExecute);
    }

    public ICommand CopyToClipboardCommand;

    private void CopyToClipboardCommandExecute(object parameter)
    {
        if (!(parameter is string stringParameter)) return;

        Clipboard.SetText(stringParameter);
    }
}
```

**TestWindow1.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="MyNamespace.TestWindow1"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyNamespace"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="TestWindow1" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Window.Resources>
        <local:TestWindow1ViewModel x:Key="DefaultViewModel"/>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListView}">
            <Setter Property="View">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <GridView>
                        <GridViewColumn>
                            <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Person}">
                                    <Grid>
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Id}" />
                                    </Grid>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn>
                        <GridViewColumn>
                            <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Person}">
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}">
                                        <!--<TextBlock.ContextMenu>
                                            <ContextMenu>
                                                <MenuItem Header="ATTEMPT 1"
                                                          Command="{Binding CopyToClipboardCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListView}}}"
                                                          CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedItem, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListView}}}"
                                                          />
                                            </ContextMenu>
                                        </TextBlock.ContextMenu>-->
                                    </TextBlock>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn>
                    </GridView>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <!--<Setter Property="ContextMenu">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ContextMenu>
                        <MenuItem Header="ATTEMPT 2"
                                  Command="local:TestWindow1StaticCommands.StaticCommand"
                                  CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedItem, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListView}}}"/>
                    </ContextMenu>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>-->
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Window.DataContext>
        <StaticResource ResourceKey="DefaultViewModel"/>
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Grid>
        <ListView x:Name="myListView" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Persons}">
            <!--<ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                    <Setter Property="ContextMenu">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ContextMenu>
                                <MenuItem Header="ATTEMPT 3"
                                          Command="local:TestWindow1StaticCommands.StaticCommand"
                                          CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"/>
                            </ContextMenu>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>-->
            <!--<ListView.ContextMenu>
                <ContextMenu>
                    <MenuItem Header="ATTEMPT 4"
                          Command="{Binding CopyToClipboardCommand}"
                          CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=myListView}" />
                </ContextMenu>
            </ListView.ContextMenu>-->
            <!--<ListView.ContextMenu>
                <ContextMenu DataContext="{Binding ElementName=myListView}">
                    <MenuItem Header="ATTEMPT 5"
                              Command="local:TestWindow1StaticCommands.StaticCommand"
                              CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=myListView}" />
                </ContextMenu>
            </ListView.ContextMenu>-->
        </ListView>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**TestWindow1StaticCommands.cs**

```
public static class TestWindow1StaticCommands
{
    public static RelayCommand StaticCommand = new RelayCommand(x =>
        Clipboard.SetText(x.ToString()));
}
```

Comment: the context menu is rendered in its own window so there is no relative listview any more.

Comment: Bind the SelectedItem to a viewmodel property and use that for the command

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, that the `ContextMenu` is rendered in its own window, so there is no relative `ListView` you can rely on.

You can achieve this with a `RoutedUICommand` and the `CommandBinding` like

```xml
<Window x:Class="WpfApp.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        Title="MainWindow"
        Width="800"
        Height="450"
        mc:Ignorable="d">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:MainWindowViewModel />
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Window.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListView}">
            <Setter Property="View">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <GridView>
                        <GridViewColumn>
                            <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Person}">
                                    <Grid>
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Id}" />
                                    </Grid>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn>
                        <GridViewColumn>
                            <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Person}">
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}">
                                        <TextBlock.ContextMenu>
                                            <ContextMenu>
                                                <MenuItem Command="ApplicationCommands.Copy"
                                                          CommandParameter="{Binding Name}" />
                                            </ContextMenu>
                                        </TextBlock.ContextMenu></TextBlock>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn>
                    </GridView>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Persons}">
            <ListView.CommandBindings>
                <CommandBinding CanExecute="PersonNameCopyCommand_CanExecute"
                                Command="ApplicationCommands.Copy"
                                Executed="PersonNameCopyCommand_Executed" />
            </ListView.CommandBindings>
        </ListView>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

and in code behind

```cs
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace WpfApp
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void PersonNameCopyCommand_Executed( object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e )
        {
            if ( e.Parameter is string par )
            {
                Clipboard.SetText( par );
            }
        }

        private void PersonNameCopyCommand_CanExecute( object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e )
        {
            if ( e.Parameter is string par && !string.IsNullOrEmpty( par ) )
            {
                e.CanExecute = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```